# Quick-n-dirty results: View results of Procedure OUT cursor in SQL Worksheet?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sys-refcursor

Platform: Oracle
Language: PL/SQL
Issue: Want to output a procedure OUT cursor into the SQLDeveloper SQLWosksheet.

Anyone know how to use the Oracle "Select * from Table( PipelinedFunction( Param ) ) " to check procedure code output cursors?

I am using Crsytal Reports off of an Oracle stored procedure.  Crystal requires that a procedure return a cursor, which it fetchs and reads.

The procedure code I have is currently working, but I want to find the easiest way to view the effects of changes to the procedure code.  I have SQLDeveloper available, and I'm doing my creation and sql testing in that.  I would like to get a quick result visible in the SQL Developer Query Result window ("SQL Worksheet").

Is there a (simple) way to use a Function to read the cursor from the procedure? (and pipe that out to the Table function?)

Convoluted, I know, but I deal best when I can just see the results of code changes.  If I can view the record results directly, it will speed up development of the report.

I know of the Table function and a little about pipelining in Oracle.  I know a little about cursors in general and sys_refcursor.  I know diddly about types and why I need them.  (Isn't sys_regCursor supposed to get us away from that?)

The current procedure does an adequate but ungraceful series of queries, inserts to global temp tables (GTT), joins from GTT and original tables, more inserts, and more self-joins and then SELECTS the results into the OUT cursor.  I might be able to do better relying on just cursors and such, but the current method is good enough to get results to the report.

I think I can handle SQL pretty well (for our purposes), but I am not an Oracle-specific developer...  but I need help.

Anybody run across this?  The whole idea was to speed my development for the procedure code, but I've spent a couple of days looking for a way to just get at the output... not what I had in mind.

Update:
  I have tried some hare-brained schemes based on slivers that I've seen on the web... such as

```
Create or replace FUNCTION GET_BACKPLANE (
   Node VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS

RESULTS SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    Open Results for
        Select Backplane(Results, Node) from Dual ;
    ... etc.
```

and

```
Create or replace Function GET_BACKPLANE ( 
    NODE VARCHAR2 )  RETURN  My_Table_Stru%ROWTYPE  PIPELINED
AS

BEGIN ...
```

I don't think that Oracle is even considering letting me re-reference the output cursor from the procedure ("Results" is a sys_refcursor that holds the results of the last SELECT in the procedure).  I don't know how to define it, open it, and reference it from the procedure.

I never got to the place where I could try

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(GET_BACKPLANE( ... etc )
```

Sorry for any typos and bad Oracle Grammar... it's been a long several days.

Comment: What is the real issue you're trying to deal with?  Can you see the contents of the stored procedure(s) you're trying to diagnose?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, No, I can't see the results of the SP I'm trying to develop w/out going back and forth w/ Crystal:  
    1: change code in SQLDev,  
    2: change datasource location, update report for fields, refresh data in CR,  
    3: Repeat.. (in my case, 47 times... ;-).   

There may be some basic practices that other folks know, but I'm pretty basic w/ the tool.  SQL?  OK.  PL/SQL?  Pretty good for regular SQL and some features.  SQLDeveloper + PL/SQL?  Very basic use.

Comment: @Marc: The main thing I was after was if you were refreshing the datasource, because Crystal caches the details--parameter(s) and resultset.  Sounds like you're tweaking the stored procedure, which if that's true then I wouldn't see why you're doing this vs running the statement put into the REF CURSOR in a separate window in PLSQL Developer.

Comment: @OMG Ponies,  
The only reason I'm trying to do it like that is that I probably don't know how to.  I'm more a Crystal guy, with lots of SQL b/g, not necessarily Oracle, PL/SQL, or SQL Developer b/g.  Can you explain the "put into the REF CURSOR in a separate window"?
That part is just so I can visualize the results of my SP code changes (after which, I'll do the CR update to present the results).  Is there a better way?
I seem to be going around left base to get to my elbow...

Comment: @Marc: The REF CURSOR is what Crystal needs to get the resultset; if you can see the query, then you can copy everything *after* the `OPEN .. FOR` and paste it into a separate window/tab in PLSQL Developer so you can review the resultset without the back & forth between Crystal and PLSQL Developer.

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  I wish it were that easy... the procedure does a lot of ... procedural ... steps, in and out of GTemp Tables, etc.  I have extracted some of the code to stuff to review what gets stored in the GTT (which works yeay)... but I really wanted to see final results as a called procedure.   Do you think I can pipeline the cursor in APC's example? --w/o declaring row/table types (they are likely to change repeatedly until I get it right... )?

Comment: What about just cloning the SP instead as a function & change to return a SYSREFCURSOR?  I've used pipelining, but I'm not sold that the solution needs to be that complex.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I must be doing it wrong... "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item", "Cause: attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at parse time or that is not a nested table type".  Sigh... I thought THAT was what SYS_RefCursor was supposed to get rid of -- the typing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Developer allows us to use SQL*Plus commands in the Worksheet.  So all you need to do is define a variable to hold the output of the ref cursor.

I may have misinterpreted the actual code you want to run but I'm assuming your actual program is a procedure `Backplane(Results, Node)` where `results` is an OUT parameter of datatype sys_refcursor and `node` is some input parameter.

```
var rc refcursor

exec  Backplane(results=>:rc, Node=>42) 

print rc
```

The output of the `print` statement is written to the *Script Output* pane.

Note that the use of SQL*Plus commands means we have to use the Run Script option <kbd>F5</kbd> rather than execute statement.

Comment: Thanks for the VERY simple fix..., I can SEE the results from the SP.  It's miles ahead of what I WAS getting (errors). 

Can I run it from w/in a function? I'll try to pipe output so I can see it in SQL Worksheet format (easier to review, scan, page, etc.).
I DO get it to run, and I get results in the Script Output pane -- which is a pain... Line length is 22,397 characters, with the first 1,400 containing data, but at least I have output, and a lot easier than my attempt at looping/printing via DBMS Output commands.

At least I am in a position to get back to dev on the SP!

Comment: I just really like this for simplicity.  As much as some of us osmosis folks know, we sometimes don't see the simple, brilliant solutions -- just because we don't get into some of the details... sometimes I wish I could go back to school for the practical lessons.  "Applied Oracle DBA 101" or "Practical Oracle Development 102".  I think I'm beyond some of the theory stages, but little things like this are magical.

Comment: In my experience, school doesn't teach you this kind of stuff. Anyway, it is my understanding that version 3.0+ of SQL Developer no longer requires using the print command. I know that when I debug a proc, the auto generated anonymous block ends with an assignment to a bind variable which then shows automatically in the Output Variables pane. Honestly, though, it has been tremendously fickle and only shows sometimes, so this may be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  In the end, I wound up brute-force-ing it...
Step by step:
Make a query, test a query, 
create a global temp table from the structure,
add code to make another query off of that GTT, test the query, 
create a global temp table from the structure,
etc.

In the end, I wound up running (anonymous block) scripts and checking the GTT contents at every stage.

The last part was to use the same last query from the original procedure, stuffing everything into the Cursor that crystal likes...

tomorrow, I test that.

But, I'll just force it through for the next procedure, and get it done in a day and a half instead of 2+ weeks (embarrassed).

Thanks,

Marc